# pip install all packages from local directory

Tags: python, pip

I have a folder containing python packages and they depend. How can I install them all?
I am looking for something like `dpkg -i *.deb`
For example: I have packages a,b...z into folder "dir". Package a, have dependies a1,a2 etc. if I run

```
for it in os.system('ls').split('\n'):
         os.system(f'pip install {it}')
```

but name package "a" go before them dep a1, and pip try download a1 from internet, but it impossiple.
I mean that i need install some packages from directory on machine without internet.

Comment: Create a requirements file: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/requirements-file-format/

Comment: @sinoroc are u  mean some as `pip install -r < ls` ? but it dont decide my problem with dependies

Comment: I do not understand. Can you edit your question to give more details? Show each step with commands, console output and content of files or scripts.